# Inter parameter dependencies using openAPI 3.0.3

Tags: openapi, rest, openapi-generator

I've been trying to add inter parameter dependencies to my REST API endpoints using open API 3.0.3

My endpoints look something like this:

POST /conversations - Creates a conversation containing `messages` - an array of `message` objects. The `message` object contains an attribute called `type` determining whether the content is text / text_with_attachments / interactive (carousel, quick replies, etc.)

When defining my `message` schema/component, I desire to achieve this using open API 3.0.3

IF:

- *type == "text_with_attachments"* THEN `text` and `attachments` are **mandatory**.
- *type == "text"* THEN `text` is **mandatory**

Upon reading the open API spec and playing around in Stoplight, I did not find a way to achieve this. I came across this [post](https://medium.com/isa-group/handling-inter-parameter-dependencies-in-rest-apis-with-idl4oas-e5489abac32f) on medium, but it doesn't look like documentation tools such as readme.io / swagger / stoplight generally like this idea

Please help! :)